# JavaFX: Resize child node

Tags: javafx

I have following node structure:

```
FlowPane orientation="HORIZONTAL"
    SplitPane
        VBox (1)
            FlowPane
        ImageView
    VBox (2)
```

VBox2 should have a fixed size. When the window is resized, the SplitPane should grow and VBox1 and the FlowPane withing should all grow as well. When the SplitPane's slider is moved to the left, the ImageView should grow the same size VBox1 is shrinking. When the SplitPane's slider is moved to the right, the ImageView should shrink the same size VBox1 is growing.

What I tried so far is setting a maxWidth for VBox2, but when I resize the window the SplitPane is not growing/shrinking. What's happening now is that the empty space right of VBox2 is growing. Where do I have to set sizes to achive what I want?

Comment: Please show some code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the VBOX in a pane and in Scene Builder set under the pane in the "Layout" option, under "Anchor-Pain-Constrains" setting a dependency.